# Adding rc.local features to IMX6 image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, imx6

I want to insert rc.local to my wandboard. The rc.local is placed at meta-fsl-demos/recipes-fsl/fsl-rc-local layer and in the .bb file INITSCRIPTNAME is "rc.local"
So I applied rc.local to CORE_IMAGE_INSTALL_..... += "rc.local"
But i faced with problem like

ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES "rc.local" ........
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-base' has no buildable providers.

Is there any way to append this features to my image in yocto to my Wandboard or Can we provide rc.local features to core-image-base ?

Thanks

Best Regards
Must_ba

Comment: rc.local usually is an empty file with "exit 0".  Do you have extra command to write into it?

Comment: Yes , but I couldnt insert my image .It has its dependencies and providers in yocto project and I wonder How can I add this features in to my image with bitbake core-image-base command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use like below to add recipe for packing it.

```
CORE_IMAGE_INSTALL_..... += "fsl-rc-local"
```